# Add columns by merging rows in a text file using bash

Tags: bash

I have a tab delimited text file with 222 rows and 7752 columns. Here are the first 4 columns and 5 lines as an example:

```
Individual Var1 Var2 Var3
personA    A    A    A
personA    T    T    T
personB    G    G    G
personB    C    C    C
```

I need to merge the two rows representing each person into one. That is, I need to move the value from the first column in the second line for each person, to the second column on the first line for each person, then repeat this across all the rows and columns. So I would end up with just one line per person (111 rows) and double the columns (15,504). The first 7 columns and 3 lines would therefore look like this:

```
Individual Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var3 Var3
personA    A    T    A    T    A    T
personB    G    C    G    C    G    C
```

I would be most appreciative if someone could suggest a solution, perhaps using bash? I have not yet attempted a solution as I am quite new to coding.

Comment: I suggest to use `awk` or `perl` for this job.

Comment: Which character are the columns separated and can the first column contain spaces (e.g., John Doe)?

Comment: I believe the columns are tab separated. The first column (which in the real data is participant ID) do not contain spaces.

Comment: Is the file sorted by person into pairs or random order?

Comment: The file is sorted by person into pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless what language you use, the logic is the same. While bash isn't the speediest for this type of thing, it will work fine. You just need to handle ordering the reads of the *header* and *line1* and *line2* for each person and validate you have the same person and that the number of fields match and then simply interleave the lines together into a single line.

You could do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -r "$1" || {   ## validate first argument is readable file
    printf "error: file not given or not readable.\n"
    exit 1
}

while read -ra line; do             ## read each line into array
    if test -z "$headings" ; then   ## if headign not set, set it
        headings=1                  ## set heading used flag
        printf "%s" "${line[0]}"    ## print Individual
        ## duplicate each heading tab separated
        for ((i = 1; i < ${#line[@]}; i++)); do
            printf "\t%s\t%s" "${line[i]}" "${line[i]}"
        done
        echo "" ## tidy up with newline
    elif test -z "$line1" ; then    ## if line1 not set, set it
        line1=( "${line[@]}" )      ## save line as line1 and get next line
    else
        ## test that persons match
        if test "${line1[0]}" = "${line[0]}" ; then
            ## test number of fields in each line match
            if test "${#line1[@]}" != "${#line[@]}" ; then
                printf "error: field mismatch - person '%s'.\n" "${line[0]}" >&2
            fi
            printf "%s\t" "${line[0]}"    ## print the person (w/tab)
            ## interleave data for person from line1 line2 tab separated
            for ((i = 1; i < ${#line[@]}; i++)); do
                printf "\t%s\t%s" "${line1[i]}" "${line[i]}"
            done
            echo "" ## tidy up with newline
            line1=  ## unset line1 and repeat
        fi
    fi
done < "$1"
```

**note:** the additional `\t` after printing `personX` is just for spacing. You should check the length of the person and adjust as required. You can adjust the spacing to use tabs or spaces as desired.

**Example Input**

```
$ cat data.txt
Individual Var1 Var2 Var3
personA    A    A    A
personA    T    T    T
personB    G    G    G
personB    C    C    C
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash cmblines.sh data.txt
Individual      Var1    Var1    Var2    Var2    Var3    Var3
personA         A       T       A       T       A       T
personB         G       C       G       C       G       C
```

Comment: Thank you David, this worked perfectly and didn't take long to run (<30 seconds on a MacBook Pro)

Comment: Glad it helped. Bash is good for a lot of things. There is very little you cannot do with it. But, when you get into handling large arrays, it isn't as fast as other tools like `awk` or `sed` or a compiled language such as C. I've handled huge arrays and as long as you don't need lightning fast performance, bash is fine, but if you are doing an operation that you are calling within another loop (say 500,000 times), then it makes sense to look at a speedier tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
sed 1p file | awk '
    {
        n = split($0, line1)
        getline
        split($0, line2)
        printf "%s", line1[1]
        for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
            printf "\t%s\t%s", line1[i], line2[i]
        printf "\n"
    }
' | column -t
```

```
Individual  Var1  Var1  Var2  Var2  Var3  Var3
personA     A     T     A     T     A     T
personB     G     C     G     C     G     C
```

The `sed 1p file` is to print the header twice so awk can see the header twice just like the rest of the data.

Comment: Thank you glenn. I received an error on the terminal: "column: line too long"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. I got everything into an array and just looped through it.

```
readarray huge_array < <(tail -n +2 test.txt)

i=0;
while [ $i -lt ${#huge_array[@]} ] 
do
     name_of_person="$( echo ${huge_array[i]} | awk '{print $1}' )"
     rows_person_one="$( echo ${huge_array[i]} |  awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " };{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}')"
     rows_person_one_second_line="$( echo ${huge_array[i+1]} | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " };{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}')"
     echo "$name_of_person $rows_person_one $rows_person_one_second_line"
     ((i+=2))

 done
```

Where test.txt contains :

```
$ cat> test.txt
Individual Var1 Var2 Var3
personA    A    A    A
personA    T    T    T
personB    G    G    G
personB    C    C    C
```

And the output is :

```
personA A A A  T T T
personB G G G  C C C
```

By the way you can change the printing line for :

```
 printf "$name_of_person \t $rows_person_one \t $rows_person_one_second_line \n"
```

if what you want is a tabulated output.

Greetings!

### EDIT

For some cases where you do not have "readarray" on your system you can use this :

```
while IFS= read -r line 
do
     huge_array+=("$line") 
done < <(tail -n +2 test.txt)

i=0;
while [ $i -lt ${#huge_array[@]} ] 
do
    name_of_person="$( echo ${huge_array[i]} | awk '{print $1}' )"
    rows_person_one="$( echo ${huge_array[i]} |  awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " };{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}')"
    rows_person_one_second_line="$( echo ${huge_array[i+1]} | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " };{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}')"
    printf "$name_of_person \t $rows_person_one \t $rows_person_one_second_line \n"
    ((i+=2))

done
```

Comment: Thank you Matias. I received the following error when trying to read the data into an array: "-bash: readarray: command not found". Do I need to install this package?

Comment: @oneill I have edited my answer to fix your problem. You can check now.

Answer (score 0):

This allows for N number of personN and varN.

```
$ /tmp/x.sh
Individual,Var1,Var2,Var3,Var1,Var2,Var3
personA,A,A,A,T,T,T
personB,G,G,G,C,C,C

$ cat /tmp/x.sh
#!/bin/sh

input=/tmp/input.txt

awk '
  NR==1{
    header=$0;
    $1="";
    vars=$0
  }
  NR>1 {
    person=$1;
    if(count[person]){$1=""};
    array[person]=sprintf("%s %s",array[person],$0);
    count[person]++
  }
  END{
    for(i in count){max=(max>c[i])?max:count[i]}
    for(i=2;i<=max;i++){header=sprintf("%s %s",header,vars)}
    print header;
    for (i in array){print array[i]}
  }' $input \
| sed 's/^ *//'\
| tr -s ' ' ','  # ',' because i can see ',' and not tabs on screen
```